# Misc-Fixed fonts and font height

Tags: fonts, faces, linux

I use the [`Misc-Fixed`](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs-fonts.html) fonts because I enjoy non-antialiased fonts.  They are designed *per height*, and tolerate shrinking badly.  For instance, in the following example, the default font is set to `9x15` and the face used for the sub and superscript just indicates `(:height 0.8)`:

[image]

—To be honest, I'm not even sure what Emacs is doing here, as it ends up using a serifed font.

**Question:** How can I make my fonts great again?  Many other faces are defined using an `height` setting; I'd like to map, e.g., an height of `0.8` to the font `8x13`, an height of `0.6` to `7x13`, etc…

*(On GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.20.9) of 2016-09-18)*

Comment: That would not answer the question, but I'd be interested in a font-set that would achieve the same result.  Removing anti-aliasing and hinting from usual fonts gives an awful result, though.  I guess I'm searching for a `9x15` font that could be resized—resizing happens rarely enough that I could tolerate anti-aliasing there—but it has to be designed so that it is not scaled at the size I need it most.